# Animation after aimation

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 1024;
    height: 768;
}

#Login {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 190px;
    position: relative;
    top: 550px;
    left: 650px;
}

#pLogin {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#IDiscord {
     position: relative;
     top: 85px;
     left: 550px;
     width: 405px;
     height: 360px;
}

#ITwitter {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 700px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    animation-name: idITwitter;
    animation-duration: 5s; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.IMTwitter {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 700px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    animation-name: classIMTwitter;
    animation-duration: 5s; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes idITwitter {
  0% {
      bottom: 400px;
      left: 700px;
  }
  95% {
      bottom: 106px;
  }
}

@keyframes classIMTwitter {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(70deg);
        transform: rotate(70deg);
    }
    100% {
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Media Maniac</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Animation/Animation.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='../Javascript/Animation/wow.js'></script>
      </head>
  </html>
    <body>
      <div id="Login">
        <Log id="pLogin">Log in</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id="IDiscord" src="../img/Hindex/Discord_outline.png">
      </div>
      <div>
         <img id="ITwitter" class="IMTwitter" src="../img/Hindex/Twitter.png">
      </div>
    </body>
```

Im trying to code  the main page of a website Im creatig and Im trying to achieve a fall animation in css and then im trying to rotate an image. I realize that there probaly are better ways to do this, but this should work, shouldnt it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. There may be a simple souloution i overlooked or a typo of some sort(or my brain doesnt work)but yea, i think that css should defintly work.

Comment: Why don't you use the animation shorthand property? Also, using the `-o` vendor prefix is really not needed anymore. It is used to support a version of Opera that is totally dead with a 0% market share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both id and class refer to the same `img` you can omit the class and add on the animation property the two animations like this:

```
#ITwitter {
...
animation-name: idITwitter, classIMTwitter;
...
}
```

Working snippet:

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 1024;
    height: 768;
}

#Login {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 190px;
    position: relative;
    top: 550px;
    left: 650px;
}

#pLogin {
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#IDiscord {
     position: relative;
     top: 85px;
     left: 550px;
     width: 405px;
     height: 360px;
}

#ITwitter {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 700px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    animation-name: idITwitter, classIMTwitter;
    animation-duration: 5s; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
/*    animation-play-state: paused;*/
}


@keyframes idITwitter {
  0% {
      bottom: 400px;
      left: 700px;
  }
  95% {
      bottom: 106px;
  }
}

@keyframes classIMTwitter {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(70deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(70deg);
        transform: rotate(70deg);
    }
    100% { 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="Login">
        <Log id="pLogin">Log in</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id="IDiscord" src="../img/Hindex/Discord_outline.png">
      </div>
      <div>
         <img id="ITwitter"  src="https://www.matrixgroup.net/snackoclock/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/twitter-bird-light-bgs.png">
      </div>
```